# Where can we find res.partner model in Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I want to search for `res.partner` model. I thought that, it is located in contacts module but there is no model in it. So where can I find `res.partner` model.

Comment: Adding the tag `odoo-10` might help you reach the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

In odoo v10 res.partner model is there in

> **Odoo v10 => odoo => addons => base => res => res_partner.py**

`res.partner` model is there in base module directly in all version of odoo. You can say base module is the kernel of Odoo, needed for all installation.

Generally following menus created for `res.partner`

Customer menu under Sales.

Supplier menu under Purchase.